# Which ACL is needed to view custom fields in search listings?

Tags: custom-fields, profile, permissions, acl, search-results

We want to display custom search results to our CRM users. We have enabled a default profile for search lists that combines core fields and custom fields. Admins see search results with all these fields, but authenticated CRM users without special permissions only see the core fields, not the custom fields.

Authenticated users can view and edit these custom fields thanks to specific ACLs, and yet they don't appear in their search results. If Drupal permission "CiviCRM: access all custom data" is enabled for authenticated users, then they see these custom fields. However, we don't want to enable this permission for all authenticated users. I have tried to set an ACL to solve this problem, unsuccessfully. Any hints about what are we missing?